# Finding height of an element inside iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, xhtml

I just tried a selector, something like this

```
$('#message_type_popup').contents().find('#bb-main-content').height();
```

and it's resulting

`Error: Permission denied for <file://> to get property HTMLDocument.ownerDocument from <http://www.sample.com>.`

I just tried it locally. It works if I'm loading the iframe from same domain.

Answer (score 1):

If the iframe is not from the same domain, you will not be able to access its contents with javascript due to browser [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: is any other solutions available to find the height of the the content inside the iframe ?

Comment: You could grab the HTML server side, and load it into the client from the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

This is to prevent cross-site scripting attacks (XSS). Content of the iframe should be originating from the same domain in order for you to be able to manipulate it through JavaScript

Some interesting reading on the topic: http://pipwerks.com/2008/11/30/iframes-and-cross-domain-security-part-2/